# Passing parameters to function: Cannot bind argument to parameter

Tags: powershell

I am receiving the following error message:

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is an empty string.

from this code:

```
$image = "image"
$logfile_name = "log.txt"

cleanup $image $logfile_name

function cleanup($image, $logfile) {
   log_message "message" $logfile
}

function log_message($msg, $logfile) {
    $msg | Tee-Object -Append -FilePath "$logfile"
}
```

I've tried with and without the quotes, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: I've tried to echo the value and it existing but when I ran it in the log_message command it says its null/empty string.

Comment: Your code does not work for me since your not using the word "function" to create the two functions.
function cleanup(..) instead of just cleanup(..) and you should put the functions before calling it in your script.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh, That's what I am aiming for, it should create the file if non existent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work for me since your not using the word "function" to create the two functions: function cleanup(..) instead of just cleanup(..) and you should put the functions before calling it in your script.

I've changed your code as follows and it works now:

```
function cleanup($image, $logfile) {
   log_message "message" $logfile
}

function log_message($msg, $logfile) {
    $msg | Tee-Object -Append -FilePath "$logfile"
}

$image = "image"
$logfile_name = "log.txt"

cleanup $image $logfile_name
```

Comment: It's a typo my apologies, I've wrote my code with the function keyword

Comment: Yeah it does, is it the function order that did the change?

Comment: The script executes from the top to the bottom. So, before you can call a function, you need to create it.